# In Doctrine2 when calling getIdentityMap function what should expect to be returned?

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, entitymanager

I'm trying to find out what exactly is returned after calling the getIdentityMap method on the 
UnitOfWork object.

What I actually can see is an array of entities that may correspond to the latest entity I i was flushed the Entity Manager.

I'm accessing getUnitOfWork in \Doctrine\ORM\Event\PostFlushEventArgs after postFlush event.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Please show some code and you are using. That will help others to answer your question.

Comment: @Archlight, will do next time. thanks

Answer (score 0):

The code [is well documented](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php)

```
/**
 * The identity map that holds references to all managed entities that have
 * an identity. The entities are grouped by their class name.
 * Since all classes in a hierarchy must share the same identifier set,
 * we always take the root class name of the hierarchy.
 *
 * @var array
 */
private $identityMap = array();
```

The [design pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/identityMap.html) generally used within ORMs to ensure that only one *instance* of the managed entity is loaded per request.

So the first time you query the entity manager, it will be loaded from the database and a pointer to this entity is then added to the identity map array with a unique key (the `spl_object_id()`). On the second call the *same instance* is returned.

Comment: so for example if i updated one entity that is mapped to 2 other entities, the first element in $uow->getIdentityMap() will be the represntaion of that entity?. in other words if entity A was persisted (and it's mapped to entities B & C) will result in array(A,B,C)? 
is there a meaning to the order of elements in the array?
thanks

Comment: The identity map is populated on *select*, rather than update. So `$em->find('A', $id)` will first check the map and see if the `A` record is within it. If it's not within the map then Doctrine needs to load the entity from the database and add it to the map. Any subsequent calls to find 'A' with the same ID would just return the already loaded object instance rather than hit the database. The *order* is not relevant, it will depend on the order you load the entities.